# Can charge move without accelerating?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electrons

According to Wikipedia :

*"An electric potential (also called the electric field potential, potential drop or the electrostatic potential) is the amount of work needed to move a unit positive charge from a reference point to a specific point inside the field without producing any acceleration"*

But how can any object be moved without producing even the slightest acceleration upon impact ?

Comment: Imagine moving the charge very very slowly. The acceleration would be negligible. And this is the case, that this definition is made for.

Comment: @Steeven but that would mean their kinetic energy is also negligible, no ? i mean, for example if we need to calculate collisions that would generate heat in a resistor

Comment: @physicsnewbie This is not saying the only way to find potential is to move a charge slowly from the reference point to the point in question. This is just one way to look at what the potential is. Electric potential exists in all cases with charged particles and electric fields.

Comment: @AaronStevens i just think of an electron as an object falling inside a gravitational field, and can't imagine it not accelerating

Comment: Electrons can undergo acceleration. And objects in a gravitational field are still able to move at constant speed. Just take a book and move it up or down at a constant speed. I'm not sure I'm understanding what your question is here.

Comment: @AaronStevens but even the book will be accelerated upwards moving it from it's previous position, just like you need to accelerate an object at rest towards any direction, to make it move, no ?

Comment: You can move an object very quickly and very slowly to the same high speed. When done slowly, the acceleration is small. And it also takes a lot of time. In thermodynamics you also often assume negligible accelerations, to avoid extra terms with forces that would cause the accelerations. You must then remember that in real life that particular definition is not the full picture.

Comment: @Steeven Yes, but the definition of the "electric potential" in wikipedia, forbids any acceleration and that's what made me wonder how is that possible.

Comment: @Steeven  And this shows a charge being accelerated  http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester2/c05_Uparallelplate.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if there is acceleration for the unit positive charge while measuring the electrostatic potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/320539)

Comment: Just because the charge is being accelerated doesn't mean there is not defined potential. Also, @Steeven is right. If we have a negligible acceleration then we are fine. Read it like this: ""An electric potential is the amount of work needed to move a unit positive charge from a reference point to a specific point inside the field without producing any significant/measurable acceleration." Or you can measure all potentials from infinity and have the acceleration applied at infinity before coming in at a constant velocity. Although this is an idealization also, so have fun with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is important to understand why the movement of the change should be done without any acceleration.

This is because, in order to accelerate the charge, the force applied to it has to exceed the force of the field acting on the charge and, as a result, the total work done on the charge, while moving it from the reference point A to some point B, will exceed the potential difference between A and B, by the amount of the extra work spent to accelerate the charge.

Once that understood, you should see that the suggestions in the comment - to move the charge very slow - will lead to as accurate measurement as you wish, given that, in theory, you can move the charge infinitely slow.

If, however, you want to complete the measurements quickly, there are a couple of  methods which would still give you accurate results.

1) You can accelerate the charge from the initial zero velocity at point A to any desired velocity and slow it down to zero velocity, when you arrive to point B, in which case the positive work spent to accelerate the charge will be canceled by the negative work spent to slow it down and, therefore, the total work will be exactly equal to the potential difference between A and B.

2) You can accelerate the charge from the initial zero velocity at point A to any desired velocity, move the charge at that velocity all the way to B and subtract the kinetic energy of the charge from the total work. The result will be exactly equal to the potential difference between A and B.

3) You can accelerate the charge to a desired velocity before you arrive to point A and then continue moving the charge all the way to point B at that velocity. In this case the total work, performed on the charge while moving it, at a constant velocity, from A to B, will be exactly equal to the potential difference between A and B, without any adjustments.

The advantage of method 3 over 1 and 2 is that you can accurately measure the potential relative to A at any point on the way from A to B and end up with an accurate potential map of the whole path. You'll have the same ability, if you move at infinitely low speed, but it would take more time.

Comment: "the force applied to it has to exceed the force of the field acting on the charge and" , the force field strength is the orbital the electron is in ?  so to pull  it out of that field , a bigger force would be needed just like lifting up a box would take a force to overcome the gravity force field

Comment: @physicsnewbie In the definition of potential, we are talking about a free positive unit charge, e.g., a free positron or, if the definition was for a negative unit charge, it would be a free electron, i.e., the electron that was separated from its atom earlier.

Comment: if it's free , which field attracts it ? i mean which field does it need to be "released" from ? other charges in it's vicinity ?

Comment: also, in option 1)  that you mentioned, what is the initial state of the charge, is the charge "standing still" ? what if it collides with another object before it reaches it's "destination"  what would be it's momentum when they collide ?

Comment: @physicsnewbie It could be any electrostatic field, created by a charged body, like a point charge (could be another electron) or a charged sphere, located anywhere (one foot or one mile away). There is potential associated with that field and this potential changes from point to point. Here, we are defining a potential at a random point, B, of this field relative to a chosen reference point A,  which is typically chosen at infinity. So, if we say a potential at B is x, we mean potential relative to infinity. If we say pot at B rel. to A, we mean potential difference between A and B.

Comment: @physicsnewbie Regarding option (1), it clearly states that the initial velocity is zero, so, yes, it is standing still. There are no other objects to collide with - when we define things, we need to create the simplest configuration. It does not have to be realistic, i.e, you have to use your imagination. When you understand simple concepts, you can consider more complex cases. So imagine electric field in empty space: it is just you pushing a unit charge against that field and measuring the work done using some imaginary workmeter.

Comment: but more work would be done if there were "obstacles" on the way ?

Comment: @physicsnewbie It depends on the type of an obstacle and how you go about it, but it could introduce an error in your  measurements.  For example, if an obstacle is a neutral object and you go around it, there won't be any error, since the potential difference between two points does not depend on the path. On the other hand, if your obstacle is a charge, it will change the original field everywhere, so you'll be measuring potential of a different field and will get a different result.